# Use the same style for the CalendarDayButton and CalendarButton

Tags: c#, wpf, calendar, styles

I want to create a Calendar with my own style with a custom background color for the selected/focused day/month/year like the following example:
[image]

I succeed to modify the style by changing the `CalendarButtonStyle` and the `CalendarDayButtonStyle` properties inside my `Calendar` style.

**My problem:**

I would like to use the same style for the [`CalendarDayButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.calendardaybutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the [`CalendarButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.calendarbutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) because it's exactly the same code!

They are both from [`Button`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so my first idea was to create a common `Button` style but `Button` does not cover the `IsInactive` property (used for the gray 31st of the previous month for example).

**How can I do that ?**

Thank you !